# How can I see if a function has already been called in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to save a value in a function in OCaml that I can then access the next time the function is called. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Don't vandalize your question. The answer depends on the question for context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in a functional way, as the function would not be pure.

You can use a `ref` to store the value you want, and mutate it in the function.

For example, this function that computes `a + b + X`, where `X` increases by 1 every time the function is called:

```ml
let my_function =
  let saved_value = ref 0 in
  fun a b ->
    saved_value := !saved_value + 1;  (* Increment the value *)
    a + b + !saved_value 

let () = Printf.printf "First: %d\n" (my_function 1 2)  (* 1 + 2 + 1 == 4 *)
let () = Printf.printf "Second: %d\n" (my_function 1 2)  (* 1 + 2 + 2 == 5 *)
```

Comment: @LiviaSeiler No, you can't return before doing something else? And what difference would it make?

Comment: @LiviaSeiler Surely you can read from the `saved_value` (e.g. into a temporary variable) before writing something else to it, but no you never can do something after the function has returned.